# Trying to count and print song file names using awk

Tags: unix, shell, grep, sed, awk

```
RANK  NAME                    BAND  YEAR   GENERE  DOMESTIC/INTERNATIONAL 

206:Reach Out, I'll Be There:The Four Tops:1978:Pop:3/2         
207:Bye Bye Love:The Everly Brothers:1950:Classic:3/2     
208:Gloria:Them:1965:Classic:1/1      
209:In My Room:The Beach Boys:1985:Classic:5/7  
210:96 Tears:? & the Mysterians:1964:Classic:20/15     
211:Caroline, No:The Beach Boys:1975:Classic:5/7   
212:1999:Prince:1958:Classic:5/7       
213:Your Cheatin' Heart:Hank Williams:1988:Soul:7/6       
214:Rockin' in the Free World:Neil Young:1960:Pop:5/7  
215:Sh-Boom:The Chords:1967:Alternative:3/2   
216:Do You Believe in Magic:The Lovin' Spoonful:1988:Classic       
217:Jolene:Dolly Parton:1998:Classic:7/6     
218:Boom Boom:John Lee Hooker:1966:Classic:7/6

1st I tried to print a list of Rank, performers and songs with header so I tried:
but the output still have the default header under the line
nawk  'BEGIN { FS=":" 
printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", "RANK", "PERFORMER","SONG"
print "=====================================================================\n"}
{printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", $1, $3, $2}' songs
```

I failed to count the number of songs from each type of genre and report totals of each  genre

Desired output is example:

classic 10
R&B 5
Soul 9 etc..

I tried

```
awk '{count+$5} END {print $5}'
```

songs but it failed to return result

Comment: 1st I tried to print a list of Rank, performers and songs with header so I tried:
but the output still have the default header under the line
nawk  'BEGIN { FS=":" 
printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", "RANK", "PERFORMER","SONG"
print "=====================================================================\n"}
{printf "%-10s %-35s %-55s\n", $1, $3, $2}' songs

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy with `awk`.

```
$ awk -F: '{count[$5]++}END{for(genre in count) print genre,count[genre]}' file
Soul 1
Classic 9
Pop 2
Alternative 1
```

- We split the line on `:` which appears to be the delimiter for your input lines.
- The genre appears as the 5th field of your line
- We will use genre as the key and increment every time we see it on your line
- In the `END` block we will just iterate over our array and print the key along with the times we have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

The same principle as JS's solution, but perhaps a bit easier to see what's going on, and edit if necessary:

```
$> cat file | cut -d: -f5 | sort | uniq -c
   1 Alternative
   9 Classic
   2 Pop
   1 Soul
```

The task has been split up into three parts - `cut` extracts the genre column from the data (delimiter `:`, extracting field 5), `sort` orders the genres alphabetically, and then `uniq -c` shows the count of each entry, rather than showing duplicate lines.